# How can I have a broadcast message sent out to all clients from within another class with socektio, Flask

Tags: python, flask, socket.io, flask-socketio, watchdog

I'm trying to have a general broadcast message sent out to all clients when files change in the file system.

**What works:**

- broadcasting a general message works fine.

  `socketio.emit('refresh_request', "A broadcasted message received by all clients", callback=messageReceived, broadcast=True)`
- getting notifications about file system changes in with the watchdog library in the console.

  > event type: modified  path : C:\appFilesToMonitor\afile_Copy.py

**The problem**:

I have to send the broadcast message from within the file monitor handler. If I do a socketio.emit() in this class, I get an error message in the console:

> File "C:\Tools\Programming\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\flask\globals.py", line 38, in _lookup_req_object
>       raise RuntimeError(_request_ctx_err_msg)
>   RuntimeError: Working outside of request context.
>
> This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that needed
>   an active HTTP request.  Consult the documentation on testing for
>   information about how to avoid this problem.

I thought that I have to somehow provide the socketio object to the class. I tried a callback function and tried passing along the socketio object. But to no avail. I'm running out of inspiration here, and clearly I'm not understanding something.

**Relevant part of the program:**

Let me know if more is required

```
app = Flask(__name__)
socketio = SocketIO(app)

def file_change_broadcast_callback(msg):
    app.logger.warning("*********testing broadcast************")
    socketio.emit('refresh_request', msg, callback=messageReceived, broadcast=True)

class MyHandler(FileSystemEventHandler):
    def __init__(self, sio, callback_function):
        self.sio = sio
        self.callback_function = callback_function

    def on_modified(self, event):
        print(f'--------------------------file change event type: {event.event_type}  path : {event.src_path}')

        # not working
        # emit_arguments = {"status": "refresh_request", "msg":"yooo de mannen"}
        # socketio.emit('refresh_request', emit_arguments, callback=messageReceived, broadcast=True)

        # not working (nothing received by clients)  (error: RuntimeError: Working outside of request context.)
        # self.sio.emit('refresh_request', "msg", callback=messageReceived, broadcast=True)

        # not working (error: RuntimeError: Working outside of request context.)
        # self.callback_function("The filesystem has been changed.")


if __name__ == "__main__":
        ...
        event_handler = MyHandler(socketio,file_change_broadcast_callback)
        observer = Observer()
        observer.schedule(event_handler, path=str(Path( app.config['webapp']['base_folder'])), recursive=True)
        observer.start()
        ...
```

**The Question:**

How can I have a broadcast message sent out to all clients from within another class. (in this case: if a file changes in the filesystem)

Answer (score 0):

This error occur when you try to access context Flask variables, normally this error occur in Background tasks, but you can use Flask Context outside of Endpoint using:

```
with app.test_request_context():
   socketio.emit('refresh_request', msg, callback=messageReceived, broadcast=True)
```

Comment: Thanks Caio, I tried it, but the issue was in the fact that Watchdog uses a different Thread.

Answer (score 0):

create SocketIO instance with :

```
socketio = SocketIO(app, async_mode='threading')
```

(credit to [Flask, Python and Socket.io: multithreading app is giving me "RuntimeError: working outside of request context"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31647081/flask-python-and-socket-io-multithreading-app-is-giving-me-runtimeerror-work), Niklas R comment on Burton's answer)

and emit with:

```
class MyHandler(FileSystemEventHandler):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def on_modified(self, event):
        print(f'--------------------------file change event type: {event.event_type}  path : {event.src_path}')
        socketio.emit('refresh_request', "files changed warning.", broadcast=True)
```

All works now.