# How to deal with flask-socketio timeout for a function

Tags: python, flask, socket.io, flask-socketio

My end goal is to have a button on my website (dashboard created in React) which allows me to run a Selenium test (written in python).

I am using socket.io in hopes that I can stream test results live back to dashboard, but I seem to be hitting some sort of time limit at about 29 seconds.

To debug I made this test case, which completes on the server side, but my connection is severed before `emit('test_progress', 29)` happens.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, join_room, emit

import time

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret!'

socketio = SocketIO(app)

@socketio.on('run_test')
def handle_run_test(run_test):
    print('received run_test')
    for x in range(1, 30):
        time.sleep(1)
        print(x)
        emit('test_progress', x)
    time.sleep(1)
    print('TEST FINISHED')
    emit('test_finished', {'data':None})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app, debug=True)
```

(Some of) my JavaScript

```
import settings from './settings.js';
import io from 'socket.io-client';

const socket = io(settings.socketio);
socket.on('test_progress', function(data){
    console.log(data);
});
```

My console in browser

```
...
App.js:154 27
App.js:154 28
polling-xhr.js:269 POST http://127.0.0.1:5000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=Mbl7mEI&sid=72903901182d49eba52a4a813772eb06 400 (BAD REQUEST)
...
(reconnects)
```

Eventually, I'll have a test running that could take 40-60 seconds instead of the arbitrary `time.sleep(1) calls`, so I would like the function to be able to use more than 29 seconds. Am I going about this wrong or is there a way to change this time limit?

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to use threading [as described in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7168508/background-function-in-python)

I also needed to implement [`@copy_current_request_context`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9931738/flask-throwing-working-outside-of-request-context-when-starting-sub-thread) so that the thread could communicate