# How to correctly get current URL Address in Python?

Tags: python, request

I'm running my project on localhost(http://127.0.0.1:5000/) and would be differently on my client server. So I try tried to dynamically get the URL Address but with no avail.

I tried: `request.host_url` as showing in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15974730/how-do-i-get-the-different-parts-of-a-flask-requests-url). However, it returned

```
RuntimeError: working outside of request context
```

Here what I tried to do is run python unittest that need full URL as parameter post(), that's a reason I need it dynamic url.

```
import json, requests

from flask import request
from .base import *

class TestProvince(BaseTest):

    # Test Data
    ID               = '41'
    DESCRIPTION      = 'Province Test'
    LOCAL_DESCRIPTION = 'Province local Description'

    def test_add_record(self):

        print "Adding a new record"

        url = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/Project/API/Province/" # <-- Here I want it to be dynamic url
        payload = {
                    "Status":"AUTH",
                    "Curr":"0",
                    "Inputter":"System",
                    "Createdon":"2019-05-03",
                    "Authorizer":"System",
                    "Authorizeon":"2019-05-03",
                    "Branch":"HO",
                    "ID":self.ID,
                    "Description":self.DESCRIPTION,
                    "LocalDescription":self.LOCAL_DESCRIPTION
                }
        headers = {
            'Content-Type': "application/json",
            'Accept': "application/json"
            }

        response = requests.request("POST", url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Any tip for how can I get current URL Address correctly in python? Thanks

Comment: can you show us the part of code where you're using this

Comment: @Shadowfax, I have edited question adding code snippet for you already. Just I think it is not code error, that's why I did not post long snippet. Please kindly help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From [request](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.Request) documentation

`request.base_url` should be what you should be using. I can't find documentation for `request.host_url` anywhere.

Comment: thanks I still get error: working outside of request context.

Comment: @HouyNarun from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9932189/3632345), Wrap your thread code in a `test_request_context`

Answer (score 0):

The request object has a `.host` attribute, it will give you the IP and the port where your code is running.

```
request.host
```

To get just the host name or IP address, try:

```
request.host.split(':')[0]
```

Or you could query the [WSGI](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0333/) environment directly:

```
request.environ['SERVER_NAME']
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I've learnt, `request.host` do not work outside the routes function in flask.
For example, do something like this

```
@app.route('/')
def get_something():
    print(request.host)
```

This will work because it is in a route function.