# run separate thread after get request with flask

Tags: python, multithreading, flask

A flask's endpoint is a thread, I want to run a thread separately of it. However my code is not working properly. The get request works fine, however the thread is not running separately because the user only can see the response of the server after the 6 seconds delay.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import jsonify
import threading
import time

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/test', methods=['GET'])
def get_news():
    def handle_sub_view(req):
        with app.test_request_context():
            print(threading.current_thread().name)
            print(req)
            # Do Expensive work
            print("Doing job")
            time.sleep(6)
            print("end job")

    threading.Thread(target=handle_sub_view("test")).start()

    return jsonify({'status': 'ok'})


if __name__ == "__main__":

    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)
```

I saw [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9932189/16988223) but this seems be working with python 2, however I'm using python 3.8.
The problem is that the user is waiting 6 seconds because the delay inside of handle_sub_view method.

I want some ideas guys to fix this problem.
Thanks so much.

Comment: I fixed it moving handle_sub_view() out of get_news()